# A screw driver tip that won't hurt painted screws?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

Is there such thing as a soft tip screw driver that won't hurt painted screw tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In researching your question I came across several jeweller sites that claim that with proper technique you should be able to remove the screws without damage.

However I found this unsatisfactory, so I dug deeper, and the answer is yes, there exists [nylon bladed screw drivers](http://www.amconlabs.com/product.asp?pid=4427)

Comment: Not sure those will work - they seem designed for rimless glasses.  I don't know that much about them, but it looks like they only come in incredibly small sizes...

Comment: @Jaydles the OP didn't specify a size; but if they had, I'm sure I could use google to find a nylon screwdriver for it.

Answer (score 3):

I put a bit of masking tape over the tip of the screwdriver to provide a bit of cushion and edge protection.   I usually run into this when installing wall plates for switches and outlets.  A standard screwdriver can scrape the paint off the screw pretty easily, but the tape works for me.